# GitHub actions publishes my site and ends with HTTP ERROR 500.30

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-3.1, github-actions, msdeploy, http-error

My original question was about a deployment issue not showing `wwwroot` folder on the remote server. It turned out, I was wrong and that wasn't actually the issue. So I've edited my question (and the first few comments are not relevant now)!!

I'm trying to publish my website from GitHub to my server, via GitHub actions

```
- name: Stop Application Pool  
  shell: cmd  
  run: '"C:/Program Files (x86)/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -allowUntrusted -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp="${{ env.IIS_WEBSITE_NAME }}",recycleMode="StopAppPool",computerName="${{ env.DOMAIN_URL }}:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=${{ env.IIS_WEBSITE_NAME }}",username="${{ env.IIS_SERVER_USERNAME }}",password="${{ env.IIS_SERVER_PASSWORD }}",AuthType="Basic"'  
- name: Deploy Application to Live  
  shell: cmd  
  run: '"C:/Program Files (x86)/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -allowUntrusted -source:contentPath="%cd%\${{ env.PUBLISH_PATH }}" -dest:contentPath="${{env.IIS_WEBSITE_NAME}}",computerName="${{ env.DOMAIN_URL }}:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=${{ env.IIS_WEBSITE_NAME }}",username="${{ env.IIS_SERVER_USERNAME }}",password="${{ env.IIS_SERVER_PASSWORD }}",authtype="Basic"'  
- name: Start Application Pool  
  shell: cmd  
  run: '"C:/Program Files (x86)/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -allowUntrusted -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp="${{ env.IIS_WEBSITE_NAME }}",recycleMode="StartAppPool",computerName="${{ env.DOMAIN_URL }}:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=${{ env.IIS_WEBSITE_NAME }}",username="${{ env.IIS_SERVER_USERNAME }}",password="${{ env.IIS_SERVER_PASSWORD }}",AuthType="Basic"'
```

The above is the code within GitHub actions. This stops the application pool on the server, deploys the site, and starts the application pool

This works for the most part (no exceptions or error messages in GitHub actions) but when I visit my result, I always see

[image]

The website publishes fine with a working website if i use WebDeploy in Visual Studio

I have researched and it seems like I need to set "remove additional files at destination" is also required, but, I can't see the command line argument for `msdeploy` to do this. However, as I'm using the verb `sync` I thought it would do that automatically.

Having written that, I do believe something strange is going on with left over files. If I manually delete the entire directory on my web server, and use the command lines above, the website publishes and works as expected. The issue only occurs if there are already files when I try to run the code above

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule` in your msdeploy command.

When you are deploying application from Visual Studio in Publish Settings there is a property called **SkipExtraFilesOnServer** and it is set to **true**.

This property in msdeploy is transformed to `-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule`.

SkipExtraFilesOnServer is related to Remove additional files at destination. If you check Remove additional files at destination property then you will see SkipExtraFilesOnServer is set to false in Publish Settings.

[image]

Opposite command is `-disableRule:DoNotDeleteRule`. If you have direct access to the server you can go to the directory `C:/Program Files (x86)/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/` and see msdeploy documentation in console with:

`msdeploy.exe /?` or more specifically `msdeploy.exe -help -enableRule`

If you want to see which command Visual Studio generate during publish you can follow next steps:

- Right click on your project in Visual Studio
- **Unload Project** (if it is .NET Framework)
- Click on **Edit Project File**
- In the `<PropertyGroup>` add `<UseMsdeployExe>true</UseMsdeployExe>`
- **Reload Project** (if it is .NET Framework)
- Rebuild solution
- Publish

Now with this configuration when you **Publish** your project in the **Output** window you will see generated command for msdeploy.

Comment: It's odd. I went to server and I see the rule you described. Yet, in GitHub actions it fails. `Run "C:/Program Files (x86)/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync  -disableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -allowUntrusted -source:contentPath="%cd%\Core.StagePlan.Ui\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\" -dest:contentPath="***",computerName="***:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=***",username="***",***,authtype="Basic"` `Error: Unrecognized rule 'DoNotDeleteRule'.`

Comment: `-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule` does work. But, as I want to clear up, I'm guessing I need to disableRule, which does not work!

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions I have updated my answer please see it this can help you?

Comment: I have done this. It doesn't sadly mention -enableRule at all but, let me have a go

Comment: If there is no -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule that means you have checked "Remove additional files at destination" in your Publish settings.

Comment: That was good advice but sadly, even copying most of the string hasn't helped. I didn't copy -userAgent="VSCmdLine:WTE5.0.3.2610"  nor did I copy -setParamFile. The rest I did. After GitHub actions deploys for the 4th or 5th or 6th time, same issue

Comment: I have no idea what to say, if you are getting same issue from the image in question try to connect to the server and check what is stored in "Event Viewer" of these exceptions. Obiviously this issue can be on the Windows side for starting application or something else. Event Viewer can help you there.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new step in your GitHub action where you deploy an empty folder. It's the same as the deploy-step, but the `source:contentPath` points to an empty folder.

```
- name: Empty destination folder  
  shell: cmd  
  run: '"C:/Program Files (x86)/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -allowUntrusted -source:contentPath="PATH\TO\EMPTY\FOLDER" -dest:contentPath="${{env.IIS_WEBSITE_NAME}}",computerName="${{ env.DOMAIN_URL }}:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=${{ env.IIS_WEBSITE_NAME }}",username="${{ env.IIS_SERVER_USERNAME }}",password="${{ env.IIS_SERVER_PASSWORD }}",authtype="Basic"'
```

Alternative you could try to use an extra step that uses `Remove-Item` on the web server. Something like this should work:

```
- name: Empty destination folder  
  shell: cmd  
  run: 'Invoke-Command -computername ${{ env.DOMAIN_URL }} {Remove-Item -path $args[0] -Recurse} -cred New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(${{ env.IIS_SERVER_USERNAME }},${{ env.IIS_SERVER_PASSWORD }}) -ArgumentList ${{env.IIS_WEBSITE_NAME}}'
```